# meteor - phonegap facebook oauth

Tags: facebook, cordova, oauth, meteor

so i have a meteor app, and i'm using facebook login (and google etc) for user authentication.
and i'm using MeteorRider which is basically "hijacking" the DOM from my meteor app, this way i get also a phonegap app.
So when using web and clicking on the facebook login, its working great.
but when using the phonegap app, its not working. its making an ouath call (opening a browser and do all the process but does not automatically close the browser and bring up my app) but then redirect to my app in the browser.
i'm still trying to figure how the two works with each other.
do i need to do this authentication using phonegap api or should i handle it using meteor api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this for any oauth requirements in phonegap. https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-phonegap

It handles closing of the browser etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just released a package to fix this. It uses the InAppBrowser plugin to load the popup, listens for the auth token, closes the popup and logs in/creates account.

https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/phonegap-oauth